# how to install patches in parallel in liquibase?

Tags: oracle, liquibase, cicd

my project has large oracle sql scripts. liquibase locks the schema (DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table) when installing a single patch. How do I install multiple patches in parallel without a queue?
P.S. Oracle will independently make locks at its discretion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any DDL is make the new schema state that is based on previous state. If the previous state is not valid, you cant apply next DDL (it is impossible to add new constrain to the column that not exist). To check the previous state, you use precondition in your changesets.
So, in general it is impossible to parallelise the schema update, because the schema changes should be applied in order and the order can't be changed.
The lock on DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK is aimed to be sure that it is impossible to run two schema update process in one time, and it is reasonable restriction, so don't try to get around it.
If update process takes to much time, just be sure that you:

1. not use liquibase to change database state (add data to tables)
2. not use liquibase to update code objects (functions, procedures and etc.) in the database
3. not use liquibase for migrate large amount of data

Comment: wouldn't using another tool cause locks? liquibase has convenient functions that I don't want to create again.

Comment: ? message aborted

Comment: The proper workflow could be
1. Disconnect clients from the database
2. Update the schema (liquibase)
3. Update code
4. Allow clients to connect 
5. Run data migration in background
In some cases it is impossible to allow clients connection before data migration since data integrity should not be compromised. But in most cases it is a good idea. For example, you changed the type of column. This action is proper to do into steps
1. Create new column during the deploy the current release 
2. Run data migration as background process
3. Remove old column during the deploy the next release